# Using Slick (jQuery Plugin) slickGoTo doesn't work

Tags: jquery, plugins, slick.js

I got this problem with this jQuery plugin called
[Slick](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/) on first load it doesnt work properly [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0huKH.png) and after i click on next or prev it gets on its place [screenshot_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1otC6.png) I've tried to make slides move like this
HTML

```
<div class="modal" id="subscribePopup">
        <div class="subscriptionOffers">
          <div style="text-align: center; font-weight: 900;"><h6 style="font-weight: 900;">One month reecurring payment</h6>
            <p><h1>$30</h1></p>
            <p>/monthly</p>
          </div>
          <div style="text-align: center; font-weight: 900;"><h6 style="font-weight: 900;">Three months reecurring payment</h6>
            <p><h1>$15</h1></p>
            <p>/monthly</p>
          </div>
          <div style="text-align: center; font-weight: 900;"><h6 style="font-weight: 900;">Six months reecurring payment</h6>
            <p><h1>$10</h1></p>
            <p>/monthly</p>
          </div>
          <div style="text-align: center; font-weight: 900;"><h6 style="font-weight: 900;">Anually reecurring payment</h6>
            <p><h1>$5</h1></p>
            <p>/monthly</p>
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

jQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      var slider = $('.subscriptionOffers').slick({
      infinite: true,
      arrows: true,
      centerMode: true,
      centerPadding: '15%',
      initialSlide: 0,
      speed: 300,
      prevArrow:'<div class="prev"><img src="img/prev.png"></div>',
      nextArrow:'<div class="next"><img src="img/next.png"></div>'
      });
});
    $(window).load(function(){
      slider.slick('slickGoTo',2);
      slider.slick('slickGoTo',1);
    });
```

on window load but it doest work :/

Comment: Yes, the code is updated.

Comment: what is the error you getting? like slider is undefined or something and declare you `var slider` globally to access in both function

Comment: Im not getting any error, but you can see on first Screenshot how the data is placed, and when i go to the next slide the data gets on its right place as on second Screenshot

Comment: did you used slick.css and Can you replicate your problem in a code snippet ?

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
 var $slick;

 $(document).ready(function(){
    $slick = $('.myDiv');

    $slick.slick({
        infinite: true,
        arrows: true,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '15%',
        initialSlide: 0,
        speed: 300,
        prevArrow:'<div class="prev"><img src="img/prev.png"></div>',
        nextArrow:'<div class="next"><img src="img/next.png"></div>'
    });

    $slick.slick('slickGoTo', 1);
});
```

[Working pen](https://codepen.io/digitalify/pen/WKoJmm)

Comment: nope still not, is there any problem if the slider is in the modal? im using Materializecss modal

Comment: Check the first screenshot thats what im getting again, the slick is not working its not changing by itself with this $slick.slick('slickGoTo', 1); it just stays like that if i click next or prev it gets to right place. Do you understand?

Comment: Your right i see it, but is not working on my localhost server it's not showing slide 1 active automatically.

Comment: I've removed window onload, and there is no slick error :/

Comment: Yes right as i said earlier im using a popup but im not using fancybox, im using default modal of Materializecss here is the URL: https://materializecss.com/modals.html

Comment: im using a button id="subscribeButton", now i added this to jquery
    $('#subscribeButton').on('click', function(){
      $slider.slick('slickGoTo', 1);
    });
and it worked :D

Thank you.